# Align Input elements and labels into two seperate columns

Tags: html, css

Now this can be done easily with tables, however, i want to know if there is sensible non table way to do this.

What i want is lets say labels on one side, left side top to bottom of greatly varying length. And input elements often multiple per line on other side however all input elements align at the same left edge which is about 100px away from all their labels and is not based on the length of the label.

I could use tables or css tables...however is there another way. Because It seems not very good idea especially to update and maintain a structure that is related but divided into separate entitie[image]s.

I want to so that if it's possible to do this layout if possible without using tables/css tables...but if that is unpractical let me know.

Comment: Can you provide an illustration for your question?
Also, provide what you have tried  in jsfiddle

Comment: So you have some tabular data and you specifically do not want to use HTML tables or imitate them in CSS? The last sentence in the question makes it very unclear what you want. Moreover, the specific structure of the data, the desired visual appearance, or the requirements on maintainability have not been specified.

Comment: Please add a simple picture to show what you are trying.

Comment: Also, another important point to consider: with regards to the width of the labels. Should they be flexible in the sense that the width depends on the widest label, or are you going for a fixed-width solution?

Comment: flexible should be an option..maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy peasy!

1. Wrap both your label *and field* with a `<label>` tag.
2. Wrap the label text with a `<span>`.
3. Style the `<label>` with `display: block`.
4. Style the `<span>` with `display: inline-block` with a width.

---

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <label>
        <span>Name</span>
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Email</span>
        <input type="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Password</span>
        <input type="password" />
    </label>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
label
{
    display: block;
}

label span
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```

---

**Example Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/3aJyd/2/

Comment: labels should be right aligned while inputs should be left.

Comment: If you want the label right-aligned, simply add `text-align: right;` to the `<span>` tag. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3aJyd/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can easily obtain the layout using flex display.

http://jsfiddle.net/s24Tx/

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="left">

<div><label>Name</label></div>
<div><label>Address</label></div>
<div><label>Country</label></div>
<div><label>ZipCode</label></div>
<div><label>Amount of Contacts</label></div>
<div><label>Fav type of Color</label></div>
<div><label>Previous Choice of Color</label></div>
<div><label>Phone Number</label></div>
<div><label>Email Address</label></div>

</div>

<div class="right">

<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>
<div><input type="text"></div>

</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
body{display: flex; justify-content:center;}
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.container > .right {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.container > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.container > div.left {
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.left > div, .right > div {
    margin: 5px 0;
    height: 1.5em;
}
div.right > div:nth-child(3n-1) input {
    width: 50%;
}
input{border:1px solid;font-size: inherit;}
```